# Select all rows using WHERE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a query with a where, I need to be able to still thorw all rows as a result.

For example:

```
declare @Crit nvarchar(15)
set @Crit = 'Package'; --as an example

IF @Crit = ''
    ¿¿??

SELECT *  FROM Criterios
WHERE CRITERIO = @Crit
```

In this case, if I set the value of @Crit to 'Package', it works like a normal query, but if I do not set any value @Crit = '', and the query throws nothing.

What I am trying to do inside the if, is to expecify a value that equals to everything, sort of the * from selects.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: are you looking for `LIKE`?

Comment: `where CRITERIO = case when @Crit = '' then CRITERIO else @Crit end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're talking about a conditional WHERE clause, which can be achieved a number of ways.

One approach is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Criterios
WHERE (CRITERIO = @Crit OR @Crit = '')
```

Another way is to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Criterios'

IF (@Crit <> '')
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE CRITERIO = @Crit'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Crit VARCHAR(10)', @Crit
```

There are pros and cons to each, depending on scenario. Dynamic SQL typically less readable, more complicated to write (and need to be careful about SQL injection) but can give you better execution plans especially in more complex scenarios, as you only end up with the exact conditions you need.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way doing this is by not passing a value for your parameter.

```
SELECT *  FROM Criterios
WHERE CRITERIO = @Crit
OR @Crit IS NULL
```

Be careful with this pattern though. You can create some serious performance problems. Here is a great article that goes into more detail about how to solve that issue.

http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

If you are stuck using an empty string you can change the above slightly to.

```
SELECT *  FROM Criterios
WHERE CRITERIO = @Crit
OR @Crit = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic SQL to do this. If @crit is null then the where clause is excluded, if it is not null it will be in the where clause.

```
DECLARE @crit nvarchar(15) = 'Package'
    ,@sqlStatement nvarchar(max) =
    'SELECT * FROM Criterios'
;

SET @sqlStatement = CONCAT(@sqlStatement,'WHERE CRITERIO = ' +@crit)

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStatement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function to return the first non-null value, as below

```
declare @Crit nvarchar(15)
set @Crit = 'Package'; --as an example

IF @Crit = ''
    BEGIN
        SET @Crit = NULL
    END

SELECT *  FROM Criterios
WHERE CRITERIO = COALESCE(@Crit, CRITERIO)
```